# Experimental evidence for nonlinear electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, non-linear-optics

Has any experiment been conducted which shows that, above a certain threshold of field strength, electromagnetic interactions become nonlinear?
If not, which field strength threshold is the one under which we are certain electromagnetism is linear? Can we estimate it?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with [non-linear optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics)? Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: I am not familiar with these topics unfortunately. I'll have a look at the wiki page. My question was about vacuum: was an experiment devised to test if, in vacuum, electromagnetism is nonlinear?

Comment: And there is [photon-photon scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon-photon_scattering).

Comment: Look for proposed gamma-gamma collider experiments.

Comment: Non-linear effects in media are dime-a-dozen stuff for modern optics. Non-linear effects in free-space are detectable but difficult. The answers you'd receive are very different depending on which you mean.

Comment: I meant non-linear effects in *free space*. I am aware of the fact that, in media, these effects are well known. @dmckee, could you please explain a little better what you mean by detectable but difficult? Is there a reference I could look up on which an experiment is devised to test them?

Comment: While I am not aware of any such experimental result so far, free-space nonlinear interaction is proposed to be studied by the 10^16 W laser of [ELI-beamlines facility](http://www.eli-beams.eu/science/exotic-physics-and-theory/). The building seems finished, the experiments will hopefully start in the next years.